# jquery map convert list of dashed properties into object

Tags: javascript, jquery, array-map

I would like to convert something like this (used in eg. in class):

```
var classname = "username_admin color_red strength_good"
```

into:

```
myvalues = {
    username: 'admin',
    color: 'red',
    strength: 'good'
}
```

Here's at present my closest reach:

```
myvalues = $.map(classname.split(' '),function(el, i) {
    var tmp = el.split('_');
    var res = {};
    res[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    return res;
});
```

How to continue? http://jsfiddle.net/4EvWw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated your code to the following http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/4EvWw/2/

```
var classname = "username_admin color_red strength_good";

var res = {};
$.map(classname.split(' '),function(el, i) {
    var tmp = el.split('_');
    res[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: ...what Nicola and Richard said.

Comment: This answer uses the map function as a loop and discards the resultant. While it could justwork(tm), you're abusing map.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use each() like this because map() returns element of an array as stated in the docs:

> jQuery.map( array, callback(elementOfArray, indexInArray) )
>   **Returns: Array**
>    Description: Translate all items in an array or object to new
>   array of items.

```
var classname = "username_admin color_red strength_good";

var res = {};
$.each(classname.split(' '),function(i, el) {
    var tmp = el.split('_');

    res[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
});


console.log(res);
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/4EvWw/1/

Answer (score 3):

You want to use .each rather than .map, and define res outside of the function:

```
var res = {};
$.each(classname.split(' '),function(i, el) {
    var tmp = el.split('_');    
    res[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
});

console.log(res);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/4EvWw/3/